# MTN person to person transfer

Tags: node.js, payment

I am using MTN API and I want to use Remittance product to allow my app users to transfer money to their friends.

I got confused about which endpoint to use, cashTransfer or Transfer.

in the transfer request body the sender is not mentioned, therefor the sender is my application account not my user’s account right?
in cashTransfer, are the funds transfered from the mtn mobile money account or in cash? and can you give me an example of values of the following attributes please?
`{     "orginatingCountry": "string",     "originalAmount": "string",     "originalCurrency": "string",     "payerIdentificationType": "PersonIdentificationType1Code",     "payerIdentificationNumber": "string",     "payerIdentity": "string",     "payerLanguageCode": "string",     "payerMsisdn": "string (Msisdn)",     "payerGender": "string" }`

I don't have an idea about what can I put in this feilds